Firewalld setup for public facing and restricted services
Here is my goal:
I want to have certain ports/services open for everybody and some ports/services should only be accessible for a certain/trusted IP. The restricted services should be seen as closed (preferred) or filtered (when scanned).
Here is what I came up with so far:

add public services to public zone, which is defined with the eth0. sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=<service>
add IP to another zone and add the restricted services there. sudo firewall-cmd --zone=? --add-source=<trusted-IP> + sudo firewall-cmd --zone=? --add-service=<service>

Questions:

I'm not sure of the differences between the default zones. As far as I understand the trusted zone would allow access to all ports, which I don't need, but rather work/internal/home? Is it just different names or is there a real difference? (In my research everything is explained the same...)
For making the restricted ports look closed, do I need to do something else (like change default zone to dropped/blocked - and if so what effect would that have on the public zone)? Would blocking or dropping be the way to go?

